# unit testing a method that uses Assembly

Tags: c#, unit-testing, .net-core

I need to `xUnit` test a method that uses `Assembly`, specifically called with parameter `Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()`.

But unfortunately in unit test project, the entry assembly appears to be `testhost` not my test project. That way I'll not be able to search my test project. Does that mean I won't be able to test this method? or is the another way to go?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not all code should be tested. Extract the code where you use `Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()` into a separate component, something like this:

```
public interface IAssemblyProvider
{
      Assembly GetEntryAssembly();
}

public class AssemlbyProvider : IAssemblyProvider
{
      public Assembly GetEntryAssembly()
      {
           return Assembly.GetEntryAssembly();
      }
}
```

And use this abstraction in your code. No need to test this single method - we know it works, this is part of .Net framework. Then the code that you'd like to test should consume `IAssemblyProvider`, so you can substitute this with a stub:

```
// should only be visible in test project
internal class StubAssemlbyProvider : IAssemblyProvider
{
      public Assembly GetEntryAssembly()
      {
           return typeof(MyClassInEntryAssembly).Assembly;
      }
}
```

This way your code is tested, but you are not testing .Net framework code.

Comment: I can't seem to be able to access `Assembly` from typeof(MyClassInEntryAssembly).

Comment: Replace `MyClassInEntryAssembly` by name of the class that you have in your main project

Comment: yeah. I tried both a class in main project and test project.

Comment: do you have `using System;` in the class? See the fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/aYZLsR

Comment: apparently what seems to  work is `typeof(MyClassTest).GetTypeInfo().Assembly`

Comment: Are you running .Net Core?

Comment: Yes, reflection in Core is different from reflection in old-full-fat framework. But you get the same result anyway.

Comment: This solution doesn't work if your goal is to determine the assembly at runtime.